# Query regarding saving username and password in application cache

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, ehcache, caffeine

My rest based application is going to receive the encrypted username and password from an upstream application.

My application will then interact with a downstream application,the downstream application will implement some logic(takes 1 hour approx., don't know why) at their end and they will hand us over the response which we need to send back to the upstream application.

Now, is it a good idea to store the username and password in the cache for an interval of 1 hour as we don't want to persist sensitive information into the database.

Comment: As long as you don't save it in a plain text, it should be fine. If the credentials are coming as a plain text, make sure that you encrypt using algorithm such as AES and decrypt it when sending back to the system.